# How to debug ~/dotfiles causing gdm login to gnome 3 to fail

Tags: linux, redhat, fedora, login, gnome

I recently had a problem with my Fedora Core 15 linux machine where something in my dotfiles got corrupted and caused a freeze on login from gdm such that the box would never get to the desktop. I've narrowed this down by creating a new user and logging in successfully.

I have nearly a hundred dot files with numerous lines of code in them. I wonder if there is a place to look or some debugging method which would help me pinpoint where exactly the gdm login process is dying when it hands off to the desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is pstree.

I had added a line to .bashrc to start tmux at the beginning of each bash session depending on a -z $TMUX. This was causing X to hang in between GDM and Gnome. pstree revealed the fault.

I'm answering my own question in case anybody else ever makes the same mistake I did.

Comment: I had this problem, I can confirm if for F16 and F17 as well. I removed my 'tmux list-sessions' from my .bash_profile and the problem went resolved. What are your thoughts on this? Do you think the problem is in tmux, or in gnome?  **THANKS**